# OpenRowSet ICommandPrepare::Prepare Error

Tags: sql-server, oledb, olap, mdx, openrowset

I've got a DTS Package executing a number of steps that was working 100% correctly in the past.
In recent weeks it keeps failing on a step where OpenRowSet is used to perform an MDX Query against a SQL 2000 OLAP Cube.

I know the issue isn't a problem with the MDX Syntax because it used to run correctly in this package and if i just perform the MDX query it returns the correct results.

The server this runs on is a clients server so I cannot be 100% sure that nothing on the server has changed in the last few weeks but if something has changed I'm not being told about it.

Here's the OpenRowSet Command with the MDX Query:

```
select * from 
OPENROWSET('MSOLAP',
'Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=XVStock;',
'WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[year to date] AS  ''[Measures].[Sales Qty]''
MEMBER [Measures].[Total Revenue] AS  ''[Measures].[Sales Value]''
MEMBER [Measures].[Week to date Qty] AS  ''Sum(Wtd([Time].[Fiscal].CurrentMember),[Measures].[Sales Qty])''
MEMBER [Measures].[Week to date Revenue] AS  ''Sum(Wtd([Time].[Fiscal].CurrentMember),[Measures].[Sales Value])''
SELECT 
NON EMPTY {crossjoin(
{[time].[fiscal].currentmember,
ancestor([time].[fiscal].currentmember, fyear)},

{[Measures].[SOH],
[Measures].[SOH Value],
[Measures].[Week to date Qty],
[Measures].[Week to date Revenue],
[Measures].[year to date],
[Measures].[Total Revenue]})
} ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY {crossjoin(
{[Supplier].[All Supplier].[ACTIVISION BLIZZARD UK LTD]
  ,[Supplier].[All Supplier].[BUENA VISTA]
  ,[Supplier].[All Supplier].[CAPCOM]
  ,[Supplier].[All Supplier].[CGS LTD]
  ,[Supplier].[All Supplier].[CODEMASTERS]
  ,[Supplier].[All Supplier].[ELECTRONIC ARTS]
  ,[Supplier].[All Supplier].[SCI]
  ,[Supplier].[All Supplier].[SQUARE ENIX LIMITED]
  ,[Supplier].[All Supplier].[EMPIRE GAMES]
  ,[Supplier].[All Supplier].[JOYTECH EUROPE]   
  ,[Supplier].[All Supplier].[KONAMI UK]
  ,[Supplier].[All Supplier].[MICROSOFT]
  ,[Supplier].[All Supplier].[MIDWAY GAMES]
  ,[Supplier].[All Supplier].[NINTENDO UK]
  ,[Supplier].[All Supplier].[SONY COMPUTER ENT]
  ,[Supplier].[All Supplier].[SEGA EUROPE]
  ,[Supplier].[All Supplier].[SHERLANE AGENCIES]
  ,[Supplier].[All Supplier].[SOLD OUT]
  ,[Supplier].[All Supplier].[TAKE 2 INTERACTIVE]
  ,[Supplier].[All Supplier].[THQ]
  ,[Supplier].[All Supplier].[UBISOFT]
  ,[Supplier].[All Supplier].[VIVENDI UNIVERSAL GAMES]
  ,[Supplier].[All Supplier].[MIDIA DISTRIBUTION]
},
{[SBU Items].[All SBU Items].[TNR].[Retail].[Games Retail],
[SBU Items].[All SBU Items].[TNR].[Retail].[Games Retail].[Consoles],
[SBU Items].[All SBU Items].[TNR].[Retail].[Games Retail].[Game Accessories],
descendants([SBU Items].[All SBU Items].[TNR].[Retail].[Games Retail].[New S/W],[level 08],SELF_AND_AFTER)
}
)
} DIMENSION PROPERTIES member_caption, [SBU Items].[level 08].[sbu key], [SBU Items].[level 08].[barcode]
  ON ROWS 
FROM [Retail Stock Cube] 
'
)
```

I've checked permissions on the DTS Package and I've poured through numerous articles without much success.
Microsoft's comments on the error message aren't much help either.

I'd really appreciate any recommendations.

Comment: Here's the error text I'm getting in the DTS Logs:

    Error string:  An error occurred while preparing a query for execution against OLE DB  provider 'MSOLAP'
    Provider Error:  7321 (1C99)
    Error:  -2147217900 (80040E14); Provider Error:  7300 (1C84)
    Error string:  OLE DB error trace [OLE/DB Provider 'MSOLAP' ICommandPrepare::Prepare returned 0x80040e14]

Comment: Do we assume that the OPENROWSET command works if you run it yourself, outside of DTS?